# How do I factory reset Visual Studio Code or Delete Folders

Tags: visual-studio-code

I started to learn one language and moved to a different one. I want to start with that language with a fresh code editor. But I don't know how to reset visual studio code and delete all my data. Can someone help me? I'm quite new to vs code. (Sorry if this is a stupid question)

Comment: What is the reason to start with a fresh code editor? What kind of junk do you want to get rid of? VSC can edit any language simultaneous no need to reset it.

Answer (score 25):

You can delete VSCode related data comletely by deleting both of these or if you just want to reset your editor just delete the `.vscode` folder in your user profile.

To Delete user data directory Code:

- Windows `%APPDATA%\Code`
- macOS `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code`
- Linux `$HOME/.config/Code`

To Delete the extensions and other related data, delete the folder named .vscode:

- Windows `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode`
- macOS `~/.vscode/`
- Linux `~/.vscode/`

Answer (score 5):

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

[image]

2. Type "settings json"

[image]

3. Click "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)"

[image]

4. Edit file and leave only braces `{ }`

Comment: This is the cleanest answer, thanks Sami