# I messed up like almost everything in my VS Code, how can I start a new "life" for the app again?

Tags: visual-studio-code

So a few years back, my father got me this laptop and ever since then I have used it for a lot of stuffs and all, including programming some python and cpp. I usually code python on vs and cpp on dev c++ because back then I didn't know much about debug, projects or anything, just some basic star patterns, primecheck or bla bla bla. I have installed a lot of cpp extensions on vs code like cpp, runner and so, and environments like MingW64, MSYS (If I misunderstood what were mingW64 and msys, please forgive me), and at some points, I also messed with the .json files. Anyway, now whenever I try to press f5 to run and debug a cpp file or python file, it always point to some random folders which were created like ages ago and I couldn't delete them because something in vs code is using it. So I decided that I should ask you guys how to reset the app, install the environment, extensions and all. Any help would be appriciated.

I have took it to many different stores to install new windows, uninstall and then re-install vs code, mingw64 and msys countless of time. I'm expect that it would reset to the default state, pure blank, nothing , no extensions at all, just like when you first download it.

Comment: theoretically, on Windows, you should just need to delete the app data folder, which is `%appdata%\Code` and it should be back to default state.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I factory reset Visual Studio Code or Delete Folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62389839/how-do-i-factory-reset-visual-studio-code-or-delete-folders)